# Java: Differences in Encapsulation layout?

Tags: java, performance, encapsulation

I'm still a bit knew to Java. Only done PHP and a bit of javascript most my life. I had a question concerning the order you have your classes/methods encapsulated inside each other. Does it matter? Is there a better professional way with doing this? Sorry for the newbie question.

Method 1 (class after main())

```
public class myClass {
        public void main(String[] args) { 
            //Body Code Here
        }
    }
class myClass {
     //Body Code Here
}
```

Method 2 (class inside main())

```
class mainClass {
    public void main(String[] args) { 
        //Body Code Here
        class myClass {
            //Body Code Here
        }
    }
}
```

Method 3 ( class before main())

```
class myClass {
     //Body Code Here
}

class mainClass {
    public static main(String[] args) { 
     //Body Code Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile any of those? Only one of them works.

Comment: he did not try any of them i guess.

Comment: This is just a rough sudo code. Not trying to compile. I'm just curious in the order you have the main() located at. I fixed the above code. And thanks for all the down votes. It has been increasingly difficulty to find help here lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have all your methods inside the body of your class. Outside it, you can only import some libraries for example java.util.Scanner(for reading from the console).
And you can insert methods before or after the Main method, both ways when you run the program they will be read.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I was not sure if there were any pro's/con's to having the class declare ether before or after main(). I do understand if you declare a class inside main() that permissions to variables might change.

Answer (score 2):

Your main method, as any other method, must be within a class. Therefore only the first method would work.

Answer (score 0):

***Your first method will work.***

as the main method should be in the class then only jvm will compile it.